# Passing parameters into python program on cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I have a program that have arguments are 3 files: 2pdf and 1 txt. I enter it on console with hands.

```
path_text = input("Enter path to text file ")
path_pdf_first = input("Enter path to fist pdf file ")
path_pdf_second = input("Enter path to second pdf file ")
```

How i can use this programm from cmd like this

```
python program.py *path1* *path2* *path3*
```

Instead with hands and "Enter" again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sys.argv` to take parameter using cmd

```
import sys
path_text = sys.argv[1] # parameter number 1
path_pdf_first = sys.argv[2] # parameter number 2
path_pdf_second = sys.argv[3] # parameter number 3
```

**Note:**

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script

Comment: Thx its help me

Comment: @shadow1337, then please read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)